# Validating Bulk phone Number with Numverify web API in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is what I have done so far base on what I saw on their documentation page

The phone list is paste separated by comma(,) in a line break inside the textarea
e.g
2144667308,
6823259843,
2173196699,
6163091855,
6163093109

with the below code it only saved all the above listed number inside Invalid_Phones_numbers.txt, please any help will be more appreciated

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <form action="test2.php" method="post">
<textarea name="input" rows="8" cols="20" required></textarea>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit"> Submit </button>
  </form>
  </center>
</body>
</html>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //$leads_gatewayapi=array($_POST['leads_gatewayapi']);
    $input = array($_POST['input']);

    foreach ($input as $msisdn) {
        $json['input'][] = ['msisdn' => $msisdn];

        //$msg_gatewayapi=$_POST['msg_gatewayapi'];

        $api_multiple = "c375c6c106b14d830b7*********";

        $country_code_m = "US";

        echo $msisdn; // this is to know maybe array value passes( 2144667308, 6823259843, 2173196699, 6163091855, 6163093109 as the output)

        $ch = curl_init('http://apilayer.net/api/validate?access_key=' . $api_multiple . '&number=' . $msisdn . '&country_code=' . $country_code_m);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Store the data:
        $json = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        // Decode JSON response:
        $validationResult = json_decode($json, true);
        //$obj = json_decode($resu);

        if (empty($validationResult['carrier'])) {
            $myfile = fopen("Phone_Check_Result/Invalid_Phones_numbers.txt", "w");
            $txt = $msisdn . "\n";
            fwrite($myfile, $txt);
            fclose($myfile);
        } elseif (!empty($validationResult['carrier']) && ($validationResult['line_type'] == "mobile")) {
            $myfile = fopen("Phone_Check_Result/Valid_Mobile_numbers.txt", "w");
            $txt = $msisdn . "\n";
            fwrite($myfile, $txt);
            fclose($myfile);
        } elseif (!empty($validationResult['carrier']) && ($validationResult['line_type'] == "landline")) {
            $myfile = fopen("Phone_Check_Result/Valid_Landline_numbers.txt", "w");
            $txt = $msisdn . "\n";
            fwrite($myfile, $txt);
            fclose($myfile);
        }

    }

    if ($validationResult) {
        echo "Its Working!!!";
    }

    $validationResult['valid'];
    $validationResult['number'];
    $validationResult['local_format'];

    $validationResult['international_format'];
    $validationResult['country_prefix'];
    $validationResult['country_code'];

    $validationResult['country_name'];
    $validationResult['location'];
    $validationResult['carrier'];
    $validationResult['line_type'];
}
?>
```

Comment: please do not show you api key in source code !

Answer (score 0):

@Sami, The api code you see is for illustrations purposes, not a working one...